# Completion Block handing empty array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, completionhandler

I have a class in which I am trying to use some generic code to build arrays for multiple collection views and pass an array of data to the viewcontroller where the collection view is.

The problem I have just now is that the result is being passed to the completion handler before the query is complete.

What am I doing wrong here? Theoretically it should work I think.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class BuildArray: UICollectionViewController {
    class func buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: String, sender: UIViewController, completeBlock: (_ result: Any) -> Void) {
        struct collectionStruct {
            var name : String
            var description : String
            var title : String
            var image : PFFile
            var id: String
        }

        var collectionArray = [collectionStruct]()

        //var queryFromSource =
        var fromClass = ""
        var fromName = ""
        var fromDescription = ""
        var fromTitle = ""
        var fromImage = ""

        //------------------------------------------------------------- set the class to query based off the collection

        if queryForCollection == "Pack" {
            fromClass = "Pack"
            fromName = "packName"
            fromDescription = "packDescription"
            fromTitle = "packTitle"
            fromImage = "packImage"
        } else if queryForCollection == "Part" {
            fromClass = "Part"
            fromName = "partName"
            fromDescription = "partDescription"
            fromTitle = "partTitle"
            fromImage = "partImage"
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------- check reachability and set LDS if required

        var query = PFQuery(className: fromClass)
        query.order(byAscending: fromName)

        CheckReachability.setupReachability(hostName: nil) { (block) in
            if (block) {
                //var connected = true
            } else {
                //var connected = false
                query.fromLocalDatastore()
            }
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------- find the objects

        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else if let packs = objects {
                //------------------------------------------------------------- if we have objects and were reachable unpin everthing so it can be updated
                CheckReachability.setupReachability(hostName: nil) { (block) in
                    if (block) {
                        PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackground(withName: "packDataLDS")
                    }
                }

                //------------------------------------------------------------- if there are objects loop through

                for object in packs {
                    print(fromName)
                    print(object)

                    let arrayName = object.object(forKey: fromName) as! String
                    let arrayDescription = object.object(forKey: fromDescription) as! String
                    let arrayTitle = object.object(forKey: fromTitle) as! String
                    let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: fromImage) as! PFFile
                    let arrayID = object.objectId as String!

                    collectionArray.append(collectionStruct(name: arrayName, description: arrayDescription, title: arrayTitle, image: arrayImage, id: arrayID!))
                }

                //                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                //                    sender.collectionView?.reloadData()
                //                    sender.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
                //                    sender.collectionView?.setScaledDesginParam(scaledPattern: .verticalCenter, maxScale: 1.0, minScale: 0.8, maxAlpha: 1.0, minAlpha: 0.5)
                //                    sender.collectionView?.scaledVisibleCells()
                //
                ////                    if sender.collectionView?.dataSource?.collectionView(sender.collectionView!, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)) != nil {
                ////                        //self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.packIndexLDS, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
                ////                        let rect = sender.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: sender.packIndexLDS, section: 0))?.frame
                ////                        self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(rect!, animated: false)
                ////                    }
                //                }
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------------- if we are reachable pin everthing

            CheckReachability.setupReachability(hostName: nil) { (block) in
                if (block) {
                    PFObject.pinAll(inBackground: objects, withName: "packDataLDS")
                }
            }

        })

        completeBlock(result: collectionArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you indented your code properly, you would see that there are mismatched parenthesis near the end :)

Comment: I don't see no mismatched parenthesis but I think that your `completeBlock(result: collectionArray)` should rather be before the `})` upwards (at the end of block named `block`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `completeBlock(result: collectionArray)` outside the completion block for the query. Move it inside the query's completion block instead of after.

You have:

```
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        // lots of stuff removed for clarity
    })

    completeBlock(result: collectionArray)
```

but it needs to be:

```
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        // lots of stuff removed for clarity

        completeBlock(result: collectionArray)
    })
```

Comment: good call, i also needed to add @ escaping in the completion : "completeBlock: @ escaping (_"